# How to debug an AWK script

Tags: scripting, awk

What are the tips for debugging any AWK script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the print statement in your code to print out values of variables/return values and so on. If you are using [gawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations), you can use the `-W dump-variables[=file]` option to dump variables out to a file for debugging.

Also, the option `-W lint[=value]` might be of interest. See the documentation for more. Other versions of AWK, such as pgawk provides profiling.

[A page of](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch10_07.htm) the sed/awk book on debugging for your reference.

Comment: So the tip to debug `awk` is to use `gawk` :)

Answer (score 5):

There is now this page: [Debugger Invocation - The GNU Awk User's Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Debugger-Invocation.html#Debugger-Invocation); mentioning an invocation like:

```
 $ gawk -D -f getopt.awk -f join.awk -f uniq.awk inputfile
```

... which should otherwise spawn a shell interface; but I don't have the `--debug`/`-D` switch on my GNU Awk 3.1.7, unfortunately..

EDIT: Found some more about this:

[awk.info » New AWK debugger](http://awk.info/?news/debugger)

> Arnold Robbins writes in Feb 2010..
>   The distribution is available at http://www.skeeve.com/gawk/gawk-3.1.7-bc-d.tar.gz ...
>   This version is the same as 3.1.7, but with a new execution engine and a debugging version of gawk named, rather imaginatively, "dgawk"...

And then:

[GNU Awk: This is Not Your Father's Awk | Dr Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/gnu-awk-this-is-not-your-fathers-awk/240158351)

> Awk-level debugging with a debugger that is similar to GDB, the GNU debugger. This first became available with gawk 4.0 (released in 2011) as a separate executable, but it is now built-in to the regular gawk executable.

So that explains why I don't have it ... time to build from source, I guess `:)`

Comment: The link to awk.info doesn't do what one would expect =}

Comment: awk.info is currently owned by parkingcrew.net - it's no longer the site that once had `awk` information on it.