# How to convert txt into html format using shell/bash

Tags: html, bash, shell, awk, aix

I have below data in a text file:

```
Details_A
name: A1
Valid: A1_Value
name: A2
Valid: A2_Value
Details_A2
name: A2
Valid: A2_Value
name: A2
Valid: A2_Value
```

which I am trying to convert into in below html table:

**Details**

[image: Output HTML Table]

Comment: Why do you restrict yourself to a shell ? Is this some kind of self excercise or a technical restriction ? Personally it should be easy to do with any kind of regex search and replace, as long as the data has no errors in it.

Comment: I am writing it in prod aix env server where I don't have access to change anything so yeah, there is a technical restriction.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: @ghoti I have uploaded my current work at http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=74381407772679912016 I am using awk in AIX server.

Comment: @user0, please put your code into your question. External links have a habit of disappearing over time. And if you're writing in awk, tag your question with awk. Right now it's tagged as if you want a solution in /bin/sh or bash. Have a look at the SO [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide for tips on converting this into a great question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this :

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
        x = 0;
        print "<table border="1">"
    }
    {
        if (NF == 1){
            print "<tr ><td colspan="2">"$i"</td>";
            print "</tr>"
        } else {
            if (x == 0){
                x++;
                print "<tr><td>"$i"</td>"
            } else {
                x = 0;
                print "<td>"$i"</td></tr>"
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        print "</table>"
    }' input.txt > table.html
```

Feel free to add any additional style

For older version of `awk`, you can use the following, tested on an `awk` implementation of 2009-11-26 (from [one-true-awk](https://github.com/danfuzz/one-true-awk)) :

```
awk  'BEGIN {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        print "<table border="1">"
    }
    {
        for (i = 1; i<=NF ; i++){

            if (NF == 1){
                print "<tr ><td colspan="2">"$i"</td></tr>";
            } else {

                if (x == 0 && y == 0){
                    print "<tr><td>"$i" ";
                    x++;
                }
                else if (x == 0 && y == 1){
                    print "<td>"$i" ";
                    x++;
                }
                else if (x==(NF-1)){
                    x = 0;
                    y++;
                    if (y == 2){
                        y = 0;
                        print ""$i"</td></tr>";
                    }
                    else{
                        print ""$i"</td>";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print ""$i" ";
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        print "</table>"
    }' input.txt > table.html
```

For this last version, `x` is incremented at each space delimiter until we reach `NF-1` which is the last word and we should put an ending `</td>`. The decision for the ending `</tr>` depends on the value of `y` which is incremented at each line and re-initialized when the max count of `<td>` is reached (here 2 `<td>` per `<tr>`)

Comment: the above code works perfectly in my local where I have gawk installed. But its failing on AIX system where I have awk and I am unable to find its version. I tried awk --version, awk -W version. Getting below error: Getting below error: awk: 0602-562 Field $() is not correct.
 The input line number is 1. The file is IIB_SSL
 The source line number is 8.

Comment: I've recompiled a "not that old" version of awk (2009) and reproduced the issue, I've updated the answer, it was the `for (i = 1; i<=NF ; i++)` which was necessary. If you have other issues I can test with older versions

Comment: I tried it in local and its generating unexpected o/p. https://s24.postimg.org/6avqfvnwl/Capture.jpg

Comment: is it valid for Details_A
name: A1
Valid: A1_Value

Comment: @BertrandMartel, when you say "tested with awk version of 2009-11-26", which version of awk are you talking about? [One true awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk)? Or some derivative?

Comment: @ghoti In fact I tested from versions archived from this repo : https://github.com/danfuzz/one-true-awk

Comment: Yes, I have tested with awk.
is it valid for 

Details_A
name: A1
Valid: A1_Value

what if data is like below:

Details_A
name: A1 B1 C1
Valid: A1_Value B2_Value B3_Value.

I mean 1st version of code was robust. In some cases, I have more than two words in a line. Do I have to check for all cases?

Comment: @BertrandMartel I have uploaded actual input data and expected/actual o/p at http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=74381407772679912016 pls have a look.

Comment: I've fixed the issue with my last update, it works with input you've provided

Comment: @BertrandMartel:  Thank you very much! It's working as expected. Is there a way to see the processing of awk. I tried with bash -x ./script.sh but it just printed the whole script(awk part) as it is!

Comment: You can use gawk debugger but its only from gawk 4.X I think. There are some other debugger available though, you can look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116600/how-to-debug-an-awk-script)