# multiline awk script inside shell script

Tags: shell, awk, scripting, tcsh

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

 cmd='BEGIN{c=0}{
      if($1=="Net"){print $0}

       if($1=="v14")
       {
         if($4>=200)
           {print "Drop more than 200 at "$1}
          }

              }'

         
awk -f "$cmd" input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

I am trying to execute shell script which contains multiline awk script inside it.
storing awk script (especially multiline awk script) to a variable **cmd** & then excuting that cmd in awk -f "$cmd" input_file.txt > output_file.txt.

this is giving an error like below

```
     awk: fatal: can't open source file `BEGIN{c=0}{
          if($1=="Net"){print $0}

           if($1=="v14")
           {
             if($4>=200)
              {print"Drop more than 200 at $1}
               }

                }' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

my questin is how do i execute shell script which contains multiline awk script inside it?
can you please help me with this as i couldn't figureout even after searching in google/reference manual?

Comment: For your concideration: [Top 10 Reasons not to use C Shell](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) and [Csh programming considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't write [t]csh scripts, see any of the many results of https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not, use a Bourne-derived shell like bash.
2. Don't store an awk script in a shell variable and then ask awk to interpret the contents of that variable, just store the script in a function and call that.

So, do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo() {
    awk '
        { print "whatever", $0 }
    ' "${@:--}"
}

foo input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much

Comment: Sometimes you have to write tcsh scripts, because that is what your supervisor wants, since the rest of the scripts are writen in tcsh.
It is a pity that the accepted answer does not answer the question, which is about tcsh as seen in the labels, which is why many of us end up in this thread.

Comment: @IvánParadelaPérez If your supervisor is forcing you to write tcsh scripts, educate them on why that's a terrible idea as "that's what everyone else does" isn't close to a good enough reason to shoot yourself in the foot like that. If that doesn't work then there's something very wrong with your supervisor and it may be time to find a new job because if they're forcing that terrible decision on you in the face of all well-documented evidence of how bad it is, they're probably making other terrible decisions too.

Comment: Having said that - defining a function to call that awk script and then calling the function has to be a trivial syntax tweak even in CSH so I wouldn't say this doesn't answer the question as it shows you the pattern to follow in any shell of `how do i execute shell script which contains multiline awk script inside it?` as was asked in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You use `awk -f` when you want to pass a file name for the script to execute.

Here your `awk` script is an inline string, so just removing the `-f` option will fix your issue.

```sh
awk "$cmd" input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

Comment: this actually helped me to resolve the error. but the script output isn't correct. awk script isn't executing properly. may be setting awk script to a shelll varaible is bad idea .
is there any way to execute shell script which contains multiline awk script.

Comment: @Ajayshifu your awk script need fixes. Debug your awk script. See: [How to debug an AWK script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116631/7939871)

Comment: @Gris Lea, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent script

```
$1=="Net"
$1=="v14" && $4>=200 {print "Drop more than 200 at "$1}
```

save into a file, for example `test.awk` and run as

```
$ awk -f test.awk input_file > output_file
```

Or, as for simple one time scripts you can just

```
$ awk '$1=="Net"; $1=="v14" && $4>=200 {print "Drop more than 200 at "$1}' input_file > output_file
```

obviously the above line can be inserted in a shell script as well.

Comment: in my case i need to embedd that awk script into shell script written by someone else. So my question was literally "how to embedd multiline awk script into shell script & execute shell script? "

Comment: a script can call other scripts as well as `awk`, or you can inline the script in the `awk` call. Not sure what you're trying to address.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know in tcsh but in bash it is also possible using heredoc :

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

awk -f <(cat - <<-'_EOF_'
BEGIN{c=0}{
      if($1=="Net"){print $0}

       if($1=="v14")
       {
         if($4>=200)
           {print "Drop more than 200 at "$1}
          }

              }
_EOF_
) input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Both shell function and heredoc are optional, as multiline `awk` scripts also work bare:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '
  BEGIN {
    c = 0;
  }
  {
    # do stuff for every input line from a file
    # passed as command line parameter or stdin
  }
' "${@:--}"
```